# Is there a place in Europe that has never been Christian?

Tags: europe, religion

Before the advent of Catholic and Orthodox Christianity, Europe had numerous religions over at least 40 thousand years, as archaeologic evidence shows.

Is there any place/community where Celtic, Animist, or other pre-Christian religion has never been ceded? My first thoughts were Ireland, Feroe Islands, or Sámi people, but they all seem to have been eagerly Christianised.

The question does not refer to Judaism, but may include nomads.

Comment: Except for [Summerisle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wicker_Man) in the Hebrides.

Comment: You could make an argument for Chechnya/Dagestan, even if they were eventually subjugated by Russia.  Tengrism and Judaism, then Islam.

Comment: @Spencer: if you know enough about the history of Chechnya/Dagestan to write it up that would be great. My answer really only covers the northern expanses semi-properly

Comment: Would any non-Christian population have dared to be open about the fact?

Comment: Some Jew communities may have survived in the same place from Roman times to present - Jews in Rome seem good candidates, and also Belmonte Jews in Portugal. However, I don't turn that into an answer because those communities were minorities and "the place" where they are is actually a Christian place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Sámi peoples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A1mi_people#Religion) of northern Sweden ([Swedish Lappland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lapland_(Sweden))) and Finland ([Finnish Lappland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lapland_(Finland))) seemed a likely candidate, but best evidence is that Lutheran conversion efforts in the 17th and early 18th centuries wad complete. Twentieth and twenty-first century revivalist efforts are just that by best account, demonstrated most  forcefully perhaps by their inability to have retained even a single historical *sacred drum* of the thousands across the region extant 300 or so years ago.

Next I looked further east in the [Murmansk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murmansk_Oblast#Religion) and [Arkhangelsk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arkhangelsk_Oblast#Religion) Oblasts of the Russian Federation, but the very high percentage of declared ethnic Russians (89% and 96% respectively) compared to the traditional [Sámi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A1mi_people), [Komi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Komi_peoples) and [Nenets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nenets_people) peoples again speaks to the unlikelihood of any true continuance for the traditional animism.

However the [Nenets Autonomous Okrug (sometimes Nenetsia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nenets_Autonomous_Okrug#Demographics) next further east, stretching to the northern reaches of the Ural Mountains along the Barents Sea and Kara Sea coasts, still comprises over 25% Nenets (19% mostly [Tundra Nenets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tundra_Nenets_language)) and Komi (9% mostly [Izhma Komi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Izhma_Komi)) peoples. Here, at the furthest northeast reaches of Europe, Christian missionary efforts seem to have been incomplete.

The same might possibly be true for the larger [Komi Republic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Komi_Republic#Religion) next south, hugging the western side of the Urals, though the odds are low.

[image]

Finally in the Caucasus, there are sevveral Islamic (and one Buddhist!) republics. However this region was heavily proselytized by Christian missionaries prior to the 13th century, so it is doubtful there is any region that was never Christian prior to that time.

[image]

- 1. [Adygea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adygea#Religions): 13% Islam
- 5. [Dagestan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dagestan#Religion): 85% iSLAM
- 6. [Ingushetia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ingushetia#Religion): 96% Islam
- 7. [Kabardino-Balkaria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kabardino-Balkaria#Religion): 64% Islam
- 8. [Kalmykia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalmykia#Religion): **48% Buddhist!**
- 9. [Karachay-Cherkessia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karachay-Cherkessia#Religion): 64% Islam
- 13. [Mordovia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mordovia#Religion): 2% Islam
- 15. [North Ossetia–Alania](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_Ossetia%E2%80%93Alania#Religion): 4% Islam
- 20. [Chechnya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chechnya#Religion): 95% Islam

Comment: That close to Georgia and Armenia, Christianity was quite the player in Dagestan too. At least the Christian monuments there would seem to attest to that?  Cf [On Christianity in Dagestan, Magomed Gasanov](http://www.jstor.org/stable/4030847)

Comment: @LаngLаngС: You're right of course - I have edited to point that out, while retaining the demographic references.